# How to add a new wpf page into a powerpoint add-in?

Tags: wpf, add-in, powerpoint, office-interop

I created an add-in for PowerPoint and I want to add a new WPF window to it. It seems that when I am not able to do this as there is no support to add a WPF form into add-in project. What can I do? Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following:

1- Create the office project in Vs 2010

2- Add required references to the project to use WPF related assemblies as explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742193(v=vs.85).aspx

3- Add a wpf window (both .xaml amnd xaml.cs ) as explained in the above document

4- In my office application, show the WPF window using mainWindow.show()

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a normal WinForms pane, then add a WPF UserControl to it using ElementHost.